# Kong Istio integration

Tags: load-balancing, istio, api-gateway, kong, kong-ingress

I have been stumped implementing `Kong Api gateway` as north-south traffic controller and `Istio service mesh` as my east-west traffic controller. I followed the blog provided by Kong but not working ...my questions is ..do I need GW and VS for my Istio service mesh ? I have been getting no routes found and the following error ..please help

> GET /productpage HTTP/1.1” 502 - direct_response - “-” 0 0 0 - “172.31.76.49” “Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36” “d9f5fa8c-910e-4764-9e5d-a3a59a64b613” “****.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com” “-” - - 10.100.135.18:9080 172.31.76.49:0 - block_all

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try using this latest guide to configure Kong as gateway for Istio https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.0.x/guides/getting-started-istio/

p.s. you don't need to install istio gateway (`istioctl install --set profile=minimal -y` installs only istio pilot) if you are planning to use Kong as your ingress.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Vik , Thank you for your response ! Do i need to setup VS for istio ? how is traffic handled inside the mesh for east-west traffic ? I now understand i use the kong ingress gateway instead of Istio gateway but still don't understand how we can replace VS and DR with kong ? Thanks

Comment: which blog did you follow?

Comment: @Kuberzepam Is there any update on this? Do we need to use istio's vs and dr for achieving proper traffic routing?

Comment: for my case it works without VS and DR but if you want to use canary deployment, you have to use DR